# Pandas groupby spotting a pattern between columns

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a large dataframe df:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Val1    Val2
A1      B1      c1      0.2    -0.3
A1      B1      c2     -0.3     0.3
A1      B1      c3      0.5     0.2
A2      B2      c1     -0.3     0.1
A2      B2      c2      0.7    -0.3
A3      B3      c1     -0.3     0.3
A3      B3      c2     -0.2     0.3
A3      B3      c3      0.5     0.2
A3      B3      c4      0.8     0.7
```

Where there is alternating pattern in each group of `Col1-Col2` for sign of `Val1 and Val2` i.e. a pair where `Val1` is positive and `Val2` is negative and vice versa. I want to achieve the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Val1    Val2  Pattern
A1      B1      c1      0.2    -0.3   Y
A1      B1      c2     -0.3     0.3   Y
A1      B1      c3      0.5     0.2   Y
A2      B2      c1     -0.3     0.1   Y
A2      B2      c2      0.7    -0.3   Y
A3      B3      c1     -0.3     0.3   N
A3      B3      c2     -0.2     0.3   N
A3      B3      c3     -0.5    -0.2   N
A3      B3      c4      0.8     0.7   N
```

`A1-B1` and `A2-B2` has a pair of `Val1` and `Val2` with opposite sign but A3-B3 has none.

I am not sure how to proceed with the above considering dataframe is large.

Edit:

Reason A1-B1 is 'Y' is cause there is (0.2, -0.3) AND (-0.3, 0.3)

A2-B2 has (-0.3, 0.1) AND (0.7, -0.3)

A3-B3 doesn't have 2 such sets. It has only likes of (-0.3, 0.3) and nothing with Val1, Val2 of kind (positive, negative).

i.e. to classify as pattern it must have `(positive, negative)` and `(negative, positive)`

Comment: Your output seems wrong there is a pair in A3 B3 with opposite sign.

Comment: For clarification are you saying that any A(n) and B(n) pair that doesn't have an opposite negative/positive then it is pattern = N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) checking with [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.htm)

```
signs = np.sign(df[['Val1', 'Val2']])
m1 = signs.eq([1,-1]).all(axis=1)
m2 = signs.eq([-1,1]).all(axis=1)
df['Pattern'] = pd.concat([m1, m2], axis=1)\
                  .groupby([df['Col1'], df['Col2']])\
                  .transform('any').all(axis=1)\
                  .map({True:'Y', False: 'N'})
print(df)
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Val1  Val2 Pattern
0   A1   B1   c1   0.2  -0.3       Y
1   A1   B1   c2  -0.3   0.3       Y
2   A1   B1   c3   0.5   0.2       Y
3   A2   B2   c1  -0.3   0.1       Y
4   A2   B2   c2   0.7  -0.3       Y
5   A3   B3   c1  -0.3   0.3       N
6   A3   B3   c2  -0.2   0.3       N
7   A3   B3   c3   0.5   0.2       N
8   A3   B3   c4   0.8   0.7       N
```

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby `Col1` and `Col2` column then use `np.sign` to check the sign of value in Series. Then subtract the sign of `Val1` and `Val2`. If the sign of two numbers are opposite, the result would be `2` or `-2`

```py
out = (df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'])
       .apply(lambda g: 'Y'
              if {2, -2}.issubset(set(np.sign(g['Val1']).sub(np.sign(g['Val2'])).unique()))
              else 'N')
       .to_frame('Pattern').reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

  Col1 Col2 Pattern
0   A1   B1       Y
1   A2   B2       Y
2   A3   B3       N
```

At last, merge the result to original dataframe

```py
df['Pattern'] = df.merge(out, on=['Col1', 'Col2'], how='left')['Pattern']
```

```
print(df)

  Col1 Col2 Col3  Val1  Val2 Pattern
0   A1   B1   c1   0.2  -0.3       Y
1   A1   B1   c2  -0.3   0.3       Y
2   A1   B1   c3   0.5   0.2       Y
3   A2   B2   c1  -0.3   0.1       Y
4   A2   B2   c2   0.7  -0.3       Y
5   A3   B3   c1  -0.3   0.3       N
6   A3   B3   c2  -0.2   0.3       N
7   A3   B3   c3   0.5   0.2       N
8   A3   B3   c4   0.8   0.7       N
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute boolean masks and combine them per group, then per row:

```
m1 = df['Val1'].lt(0)  # Val1 negative
m2 = df['Val2'].lt(0)  # Val2 negative

mask = (pd.concat([m1&~m2,  # Val1 negative and Val2 positive
                   ~m1&m2], # Val1 positive and Val2 negative
                  axis=1)
          .groupby([df['Col1'], df['Col2']])
          .transform('any')  # is there at least one match per group?
          .all(1)            # were there both True for above?
        )

df['Pattern'] = np.where(mask, 'Y', 'N')
```

output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Val1  Val2 Pattern
0   A1   B1   c1   0.2  -0.3       Y
1   A1   B1   c2  -0.3   0.3       Y
2   A1   B1   c3   0.5   0.2       Y
3   A2   B2   c1  -0.3   0.1       Y
4   A2   B2   c2   0.7  -0.3       Y
5   A3   B3   c1  -0.3   0.3       N
6   A3   B3   c2  -0.2   0.3       N
7   A3   B3   c3   0.5   0.2       N
8   A3   B3   c4   0.8   0.7       N
```

intermediates:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3  Val1  Val2 Pattern  m1&~m2  ~m1&m2  any(m1&~m2)  any(~m1&m2)   mask
0   A1   B1   c1   0.2  -0.3       Y   False    True         True         True   True
1   A1   B1   c2  -0.3   0.3       Y    True   False         True         True   True
2   A1   B1   c3   0.5   0.2       Y   False   False         True         True   True
3   A2   B2   c1  -0.3   0.1       Y    True   False         True         True   True
4   A2   B2   c2   0.7  -0.3       Y   False    True         True         True   True
5   A3   B3   c1  -0.3   0.3       N    True   False         True        False  False
6   A3   B3   c2  -0.2   0.3       N    True   False         True        False  False
7   A3   B3   c3   0.5   0.2       N   False   False         True        False  False
8   A3   B3   c4   0.8   0.7       N   False   False         True        False  False
```